# Boolean mistake with Javascript

Tags: debugging, node-red

Having this code :

```
function checkIsNotOverHeating(context, surchauffe, offset, topic, node){
    let msg = null;
    let overheating;

    overheating = false;

    if(checkTemperatureWithOffset(context.get("temperatureInt"), offset, surchauffe, "-") === 1){
        // Overheating
        overheating = true;
        msg = createMessageOverheat(topic);
    }

    node.error(overheating)
    if(context.get("overheating") !== overheating) context.set("overheating", overheating);

    return msg;
}
```

Every node.error will output in Node the value in parameter. I'm not able to understand why, but it will accept the boolean true, and not the false, as you can see in this picture :

[image]

I'm using NodeRED, and as you can see, the code is simple. My function is triggered everytime.

**EDIT : Don't take care of the -1, it will just shown me the variation of 2 value**

Comment: Nope, I can't figure this question out. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @Liam in the context of Node-RED this does make sense. I'll remove the javascript and node.js tags which should help. I need to double check but I think it may be bug in the error function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the `node.error()` code as a work around try this:

```
node.error(' ' + overheating);
```

EDIT:

Fix for this has been submitted:

https://github.com/node-red/node-red/pull/1037